# Mongoose or operator with Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a query like:

```
var query = {
    userId: req.params.userId,
    isActive: true,
    'interval.start': {
        $lte: now
    },
    'interval.end': {
        $or: [
            { $gte: now },
            { $exists: false },
            { $eq: null } 
        ]
    }
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is I want to find columns that should fit to these conditions:

- interval.end Date should be greater than now.
- OR end date shouldn't exist
- OR it should exist to null.

I am getting: `Can't use $or with Date.` error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know you can't nest $or inside some specific field. The [$or](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator takes an array of expressions.

Try the following query:

```
var query = {
    userId: req.params.userId,
    isActive: true,
    'interval.start': {
        $lte: now
    },
    $or: [
        {'interval.end': {$gte: now} },
        {'interval.end': {$exists: false} },
        {'interval.end': null } 
    ]
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use $eq operator with a Date.

Comment: You don't need $eq operator there. You can use direct comparison instead. I've updated my answer. @Yagiz

Comment: @Yagiz You should be able to remove the `{'interval.end': {$exists: false}}` part, as the `{'interval.end': null}` part also matches docs without the field.